# Parse JSON String array for individual strings/ints

Tags: android, arrays, json, string, int

I am getting information from a MySql DB via PHP. The information is returned in the following JSON array:

```
06-15 15:20:17.400: E/JSON(9865): {"tag":"get_game_state","success":1,"error":0,"GameState":{"monster":"Troll","qty":"1","exp":"0"}}
```

The json is parsed and string is built using `StringBuilder`. Now that I have the information returned I want to parse it for the individual strings/ints it contains to put them in a local sqlite db.

Here are the two lines in question

```
            userFunctions.getServerGameState(email, monster, qty, exp); //this line gets the JSON array and the above information is returned
            db.saveLocalGameSate(monster, qty, exp); //this line should take that information take String monster int exp and int qty and put them in the local db.
```

How should I convert that returned information into an individual string and ints so that they can be used in the next line of code? Any direction to some resources would be very helpful.

**update**

I have added the following lines inbetween the two above lines of code, output is a null pointer exception

```
            try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(GameState);
            JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
            String virtumon = jObj.getString("monster");
            Integer qty = jObj.getInt("qty");
            Integer exp = jObj.getInt("exp");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not actually a JSON array; it's a JSON object (cause of the curly braces instead of square brackets.)

One of the constructors to JSONObject() accepts a string containing JSON and will parse it and create a JSON object.  I can't post links yet but see the JSONObject docs at d.android.com.

Once you have a JSONObject you can use getString(), getInt(), optString() and optInt() to pull out the data you need.

---

Assuming 'responseString' is the full response string:

```
try {
  JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
  JSONObject gameStateObj = responseObj.getJSONObject("GameState");
  String monsterType = gameStateObj.getString("monster");
  int qty = Integer.parseInt(gameStateObj.getString("qty"));
  int exp = Integer.parseInt(gameStateObj.getString("exp");
} catch (JSONException ex) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

"qty" and "exp" are strings in your json so you need to getString then convert to int.  I think this code is correct; haven't tested it.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up, you're correct in the userFunctions class there is the JSONObject that is being returned. I did some research and added the edited information, do you think it's a step in the right direction?